# How to send a request on facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-requests

I read the Facebook dev info on how to make a request (located [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)) but I don't exactly understand what it does. Here's what I'd like to do. I'm using PHP and javascript.

I want a logged in user to send a request to a specific URL (with parameters attached) to multiple Facebook users (users who are already signed up for my site). Also, I need to be able to get the users that they selected and save them in the database, because only those users will have access to the URL that they're being invited to.

Are there any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you are talking about the a url request. From my experience this can be done using a simple JQuery request. You can find an example [here](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=32&number=97) and you can also read up on java APIs and how to use the methods(Google it). Hope this helps.

Comment: @atta that has nothing to do with facebook

Answer (score 0):

The requests dialog is for invitations to Facebook Canvas applications.

You are most likely thinking about the send dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Add a callback function to FB.ui call that saves the id, this will only work if the user ids are hardcoded in. If the user manually adds them, I doubt you can track it.